# Prevent an already running background process from being stopped after closing SSH client

Tags: linux, ssh, gnu-screen, tmux

I have a process running on my Linux machine (Debian squeeze) that takes hours (or days) to finish.

I don't want to stop it to restart it again with `screen`, `tmux` or with an output redirect to `nohup`.

Is there a secure way to put it in the background with `^Z` and `bg` so it will continue once I close the ssh-session?

Comment: what do you mean by "stop it to restart it again with screen,tmux.."? if you start a tmux/scrn session via ssh, it will keep alive if you close your ssh connection.

Comment: the process is already running and lasting for some hours, but i cannot stop it or i will loose data.

Comment: If the command is already running, I don't think there's a way to accomplish this. There are, however, numerous ways to do it in the future if you run it under `screen`, `dtach`, `tmux`, etc. as you already note, or with appropriate redirections and `nohup`. You *might* be able to `^Z`, `bg` it now, but whether that's enough depends on whether it does I/O on the terminal after you background it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use

`commandtoexecute &> /dev/null &`

it will run your process in the background, and prints all output to /dev/null.

Replace `/dev/null` with another file to see the output.

e.g. 
`commandtoexecute &> /tmp/file1 &`

use 
`tail -f /tmp/file1` to attach to output again

You can also redirect stdin, see this
http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/iodirection.html

If you want to detatch from a process that is allready running. Use
`disown <pid>`
where pid is your process id.

You could also change the terminal to another terminal:

1. start a screen
2. get pid of your process
3. run `reptyr <pid>`
4. detach using CTRL+A+D

reptyr: https://serverfault.com/a/284795

Comment: I would add 2>&1 to see the error output too.

Comment: &> redirects all output :D

Comment: thx, that would be the right start in the first place. But you didn't read my question: the process is already running and cannot be started over with your additions

Comment: ok, edited, check my answer

Comment: yes, thats the question: "detatch from a process that is allready running" ;) So `disown` would be your answer? Isn't there a problem then with stdout being detached? see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39714/why-do-nohup-and-disown-not-work-on-sox-invoked-as-play

Comment: brings me to this: http://serverfault.com/a/284795, Start a screen, run reptyr with pid and detach

Comment: `disown` doesen't work: "bash: disown: 4219: Kein solcher Job." And reptyr is a bit strange: i get lots of messages and at the end "[+] Set the controlling tty" Does this mean, that it worked?

Comment: actually `reptyr` works fine: http://serverfault.com/a/284795 thanks!