# Process killed on ssh disconnect despite screen/nohup

Tags: linux, ssh, display

I am facing a rather strange situation:

- ssh to a beaglebone (details : uname -a = "Linux beaglebone 3.2.34 #1 Wed Nov 21 14:17:11 CET 2012 armv7l GNU/Linux", ssh server : Dropbear sshd v2012.55)
- launch any kind of process through screen, or nohup or /etc/init.d/
- logout
- re-ssh into it
- observe that the process is no longer there..

When using a second ssh connection, I can observe that the launched process is killed at the disconnection.

I've seen posts like [What exactly determines if a backgrounded job is killed when the shell is exited, or killed?](https://superuser.com/questions/662431/what-exactly-determines-if-a-backgrounded-job-is-killed-when-the-shell-is-exited), but still can't understand this behaviour, which is clearly not the way `screen` and other disowned processes are supposed to work.

```
$ shopt huponexit
huponexit       off
```

I had to resort to using cron commands to persist the process

Why are detached processes killed at disconnection ?

Do you see other things to look for ?

Comment: Have you tried disown?

Comment: yes : tried ``cmd; ctrl+z; bg; disown``, ``jobs`` gives an empty list, but it still exhibits the same behaviour..

Comment: Do you control the remote server?

Comment: yes, it's a beaglebone sitting somewhere in my office

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems strange nohup does not work, but that can easily be put to test, as follows:

```
  { sleep 999; echo $? > exitcode ; } &
  fuser -1 -k /bin/sleep
  expr $(cat exitcode) - 128
```

This will print the return code minus 128, which is exactly the number of the signal that killed it. You can list them simply by doing:

```
  kill -l
```

Now try this instead:

```
  rm exitcode
  { nohup sleep 999; echo $? > exitcode; } &
  fuser -1 -k /bin/sleep
  ls -l exitcode
```

If nohup works, at this point you will be told that there is no such file. You can double-check this by doing:

```
  fuser -15 -k /bin/sleep
  expr $(cat exitcode) -128
```

and finding this value to be 15.

EDIT

Your last comment was quite revealing: it means the SIGHUP is not sent to the process (sleep, in this case) but directly to your shell. This can be done ony by Dropberar, of course. A little research showed that Dropbear does indeed kill all user processes at logoff.

You can turn this annoying feature by adding the line

```
 KillMode=process
```

at the end of the Service stanza in /lib/systemd/dropbear@.service file. Then either reboot or restart Dropbear.

Comment: For the first sleep without nohup, ``exitcode - 128`` gives ``HUP`` as expected. For the second sleep with nohup, the file is indeed absent , and after the kill ``exitcode - 128`` gives ``15`` as expected.

Comment: but if I don't kill the second sleep that was launched with nohup, and logout and re-log in, the sleep has been killed.. and there is no exitcode file ..

Comment: @NotSqrt Please see the edit to my answer.

Comment: Tested right now, the file I had to edit was ``/lib/systemd/system/dropbear@.service``. It works ! Well done !